# prove that the product of 4 consecutive positive integers is divisible by 24

Tags: arithmetic

How can I prove that prove that the product of $4$ consecutive positive integers is divisible by $24$, ie for any positive integer $n$ : $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$
is divisible by $24$.
I've noticed that:
$24$ = $2^3 * 3$

$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ is divisible by $2*2$ so by $4$ (as there are at least 2 even numbers, obvious)

$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ is divisible by $3$ (as there is the product of 3 consecutive integers, easily provable using congruences)

so I've proved that you can divide it by $12$ until now. What am I missing here?

Comment: One of your terms is divisible by $4$ and another is divisible by $2$.

Comment: like lulu said if you look at this $\pmod 4$, one of them is $4k$ and another is $4k+2$, meaning $8$ divides the expression. Since $(3,8)=1$ and $3$ divides the expression as you've already shown, the result follows .

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you mean the product of four *consecutive* integers

Comment: @J.W.Tanner edited, forgot to mention it in the title

Comment: Hint: $\binom{n+3}{4}$ is an integer.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I was going to say the same - your comment has the nice property that it invites appropriate generalisation for the product of $r$ consecutive integers being divisible by $r!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that among $4$ consecutive numbers exactly one is divisible by 4 and one more divisible by 2 (say $n$ and $n+2$ or $n+1$ and $n+3$).

Notice also that among $3$ consecutive numbers exactly one is divisible by 3.

So the number is divisible by $3\cdot 8$.

Comment: Answer is very simple: Since the product of $n$ consecutive integers viz. $n(n-1)(n-2) ... 3.2.1 = n!$ is divisible by $n!$, so the product of any four consecutive integers must be divisible by $4! = 24$.